# How to animate 6 boxes incrementally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html...

```
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
            <div class="box">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my javascript...

```
$('.box').each(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: 300,
                height: 200,
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        });
```

I want each box to animate in one after the other. I can do this specifically, but the code is really long with all the callbacks. Wondering how I can loop through them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You could look into recursive functions.

```
function animateBox(i) {
    $('.box').eq(i).animate({ // animate this one
                    width: 300,
                    height: 200,
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                }, 500,
    function() { // when this one is complete
        if($('.box').eq(i + 1).length > 0) { // if next one availabe
            animateBox(i + 1); // call recursively for next one
        }
   });
}

animateBox(0); // start process
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/753yU/

Comment: thanks. this worked :) this is what i was trying to do. just couldnt figure out the proper syntax.

Comment: i changed it to be self-executing...

(function animateBox(i) {
   $('.box').eq(i).animate({ // animate this one
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
   }, 500,
    function() { // when this one is complete
    if ($('.box').eq(i + 1).length > 0) { // if next one availabe
     animateBox(i + 1); // call recursively for next one
    }
   });
  })(0);

Comment: @Steven: Could you please accept the answer that solved the problem please? That makes the organization of questions on SO a little bit better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it all into a function that you call from the completion function like this.

```
function animateAll() {
    var boxes = $(".box");
    if (boxes.length == 0) return;

    function animateBox(n) {
        $(boxes.get(n)).animate({
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }, 500, function() {
             ++n;
             if (n < boxes.length) {
                 animateBox(n);
             }
        });
    }

    animateBox(0);   // start the first one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a little while, but I got it :)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/gV4fh/)**

It uses a recursive function to select the next element in line, if the element doesn't exist, it stops the function.

**The code:**

```
var i = 0;

    function animate_next() {
        if ($('.box:eq('+i+')').length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.box:eq('+i+')').animate({
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }, 500,function() { i++; animate_next(); });

    }
    animate_next();
```

Comment: Nice, just in case you didn't know, `.eq(i)` might be a little bit cleaner than `:eq('+i+')`.

Comment: I think it's best if the result set is as narrow as possible from the beginning.